# getting record from sqlite database using xamarin android c#

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin

i am using c# to query sqlite to get record using email in xamarin android,
using following code (expecting single record)

```
public User ReturnRecordUsingEmail(string email)
        {
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
            var record = db.Table<User>().Where(r => r.Email.Contains(email)).Single();
            return record;
        }
```

but when i call above function to following code its returns null.

```
   Toast.MakeText( this,db.ReturnRecordUsingEmail(MainActivity.Email).LastName.ToString(),ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a various reasons why your code returns null.
Make sure that the `User` table is not empty and contains the email address.

Beside your main question, there are few problems with your code:

1. You have to dispose `SQLiteConnection`.
2. Your query can be improved:
   `db.Table<User>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email.Equals(email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Also keep in mind that keeping users db on the mobile device is not the best idea.